# Eclipse stuck while building project, "-clean" does not work

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse gets stuck when I try building a project, usually at 80%.  I also get a heap error, even though I already increased it to 750mb and the same project previously worked with 350mb.

I tried starting up eclipse with the "-clean" command, but according to the log it's not effective:

```
!MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
```

**Edit:**
Okay, the build error seems to be caused by faulty libraries. And -clean did not work because I was starting eclipse without administrator rights (Windows 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the Edit:
The build error seems to be caused by faulty libraries. And -clean did not work because I was starting eclipse without administrator rights (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also and it happend after I updated a Jar file.
Turns out the jar I had added was compiled with the wrong version of java.